# External Rails / Node app using Active Directory for authentication / SSO

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, active-directory, adfs

I am working on a service where our clients would like not to create 1000s of their users and maintain their profiles, passwords at two different places. So I am looking for available options to integrate my app with client's AD, and what architectural recommendations I could follow.

Our web layer is in ROR and API layer in Node. I also have access to AWS and can also utilize AWS IAM if that would help making a better architecture.

Keep in mind that there are many such clients not just one. So the architecture / solution needs to be able to scale well.

I am not an expert in AD, LDAP, ADFS, etc.

Comment: there is an LDAP auth module for nodeJS : `ldapauth` what have you tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this gem: `omniauth-saml`
Works out fine connecting to Microsoft AD FS.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jlguenego/node-expose-sspi

is a node module that allows SSO on Windows using Kerberos or NTLM.

It is one simple and effective way to solve your problem. No config required.

```js
const express = require("express");
const { sso, sspi } = require("node-expose-sspi");

sso.config.debug = false;

const app = express();

app.use(sso.auth());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.json({
    sso: req.sso
  });
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Server started on port 3000"));
```